# reconocimiento de texto mediante foto con la api de card.io

Tags: android

Buenos dias.

Estoy intentando trabajar con la api de card.io (https://www.card.io/) para capturar una tarjeta y poder obtener su nombre,telefono y demas...

El caso es que nada mas empezar, me descargo la app que tiene de ejemplo en mi Samgsung S6 y no hay manera de que detecte nada. Es decir, se activa la camara, encuadro en la foto pero no hace nada...¿os pasa tambien a vosotros?

veis viable enfocar esta api al reconocimento de nombre y telefono mas que para el tema de tarjeta de credito?

Gracias y un saludo!

Answer (score 1):

no creo que logres detectar texto con la api de card.io, ya que esta diseñada específicamente para reconocer los números de las tarjetas y las fechas de vencimiento de las mismas. Lo que me parece estas buscando es un reconocimiento óptico de caracteres (OCR por sus siglas en ingles), actualmente google puso a nuestro alcance [Mobile Vision](https://developers.google.com/vision/) la cual esta disponible en las ultimas actualizaciones de los Google Play Services, por experiencia puedo decirte que funciona bastante bien. Existen otras alternativas, pero son un poco más difíciles de implementar tal es el caso de Tesseract y con el [Fork](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two) de rmtheis todo se vuelve más fácil, la mayor diferencia entre ellos es la "personalización" ya que tesseract "aprende" a través de archivos, desde una fuente hasta un idioma. Puedes intentarlo con la opción que más se ajuste a tus necesidades. Saludos